Woocommerce - PIXEL Avoiding duplicate conversion
Can anyone help me how to avoid duplicate conversations on thankyou page? If the user reload thankyou page, the conversion is duplicated in FB PIXEL. I would need to prevent this.
I found Loading twice WooCommerce thankyou page would duplicate Conversion tracking? but, if I convert to the test thankyou page, the console.log (see code) is still displayed. I.e. the conversion was restarted after the reload.

The meta value that gets stored for _pixel_tracking is just true, but then the condition checks for type-safe equality with 'done' - doesn't appear to make that much sense? (There is a discussion about this in the comments below the answer you got this from, but I still can't see how this would be the correct logic to solve this.)

There was a mistake in the linked answer code: Answer updated and works.
